# SoapUI Groovy GotoTestStep in other Testcase

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a Testsuite in SoapUI with 2 TestCases.
For Example TestSuite1 with Testcase 1 and TestCase 2

TestCase1 have a Groovy-TestStep1.
The Groovy-TestStep1 shoult go to  TestStep4 in TestCase 2
(Groovy-TestStep1 should go to TestStep4 not run TestStep4)

Is it possible ?

TestCase1
TestStep1 (groovy)

TestCase2 
testStep1 (http-request)
testStep2 invoke the TestCase1
TestStep3 (http-request)
TestStep4 ((http-request)
TestStep5 (http-Request)

Thanks a lot for your answers

Michael

Comment: What is your use? what do you want to do ? `Go there and don't run` - Explain?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to invoke test steps in other test suites. You could try something like:

```
def otherTestSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("OtherTestSuite")
def otherTestStep = otherTestSuite.getTestCaseByName("otherTestCase").getTestStepByName("otherTestStep")
otherTestStep.run (testRunner, context)
```